# Scaling a Lebesgue measurable set average-wise

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbf R^{n}$ with $0<m(E)<\infty$, let $f$ be a complex $L^{\infty}$ function on $\mathbf R^{n}$, and let $0< t< 1$. Is there a Lebesgue measurable subset $A$ of $E$ such that
$$
m(A)=t\cdot m(E), \quad \frac{1}{m(A)}\int_{A} f \:dm = \frac{1}{m(E)}\int_{E} f \: dm ?
$$

I was able to show the affirmative when $f$ is a simple function but I'm not sure if it can be generalized.

Comment: Don't you want $t < 1$? Otherwise just take $A = E$.

Comment: @mucciolo yes, of course. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer follows from [Lyapunov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure#Lyapunov's_theorem), asserting that the range of a continuous non-atomic vector measure  is convex.  The measure in question is $\nu:A\mapsto (\int_A 1 dm, \int_A f dm)$, taking values in $\mathbb C^2.$
We have $\nu(\phi)=(0,0)$ and $\nu(E)=(m(E),\int_E fdm)$ are both in the range of $\nu$, so their convex combination $(1-t)\nu(\phi)+t\nu(E)$ is too.  That is, there exists an $A$ with $$\nu(A)=(1-t)\nu(\phi)+t\nu(E) = t(m(E),\int_E fdm),$$
for which first, $m(A) = t m(E)$, and then, $\int_A fdm=t\int_E f dm$ so $(1/m(A))\int_A f dm = (1/m(E))\int_E f dm$ as desired.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with Lyapunov's theorem, so this was very helpful. Thank you :)